# get data from Access database using two dateTimepicker

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetimepicker

Im 13 and Im new at programming 
I have 1 datagridview and 2 dateTimepicker and logs/infos in access database .
I want to get data between 2 date . I saw a lot of topic about this but Nothing helped me.

Here is  my code

At beginning :

```
public OleDbConnection bag = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0;Data Source=data.accdb");
public DataTable table = new DataTable();        
public OleDbDataAdapter adtr = new OleDbDataAdapter();
public OleDbCommand kmt = new OleDbCommand();
```

I tried 2 things

Firstly :

Function for get data :

```
string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM TotalInv " +
                        "WHERE InventoryDate BETWEEN @p1 AND @p2";

            DateTime dt = this.dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
            DateTime dt2 = this.dateTimePicker3.Value.Date;
            kmt.CommandText = cmdText;
            kmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", dt);
            kmt.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", dt2);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(kmt.CommandText, bag);

            table.Clear();
            adtr.Fill(table);
            bag.Close();
```

Mistake for 1 . : InvalidOperationException was unhandled . line adtr.Fill(table) -> Selectcommand didnt start before calling "Fill"

Secondly :

```
bag.Open();
            {
                table.Clear();
                OleDbCommand kmt2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TotalInv WHERE InventoryDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2", bag);
                kmt2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date1", dateTimePicker2.Value);
                kmt2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date2", dateTimePicker3.Value);
                OleDbDataAdapter adtr = new OleDbDataAdapter(kmt2);
                adtr.Fill(table);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }

            bag.Close();
```

Error for 2. : OleDB was unhandled ,  There is a syntax mistake in "SELECT * FROM TotalInv WHERE InventoryDate BETWEEN @date1 AND @date2", bag);
Thanks for any idea and Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: ""It doesnt work and Idk where is the problem "" and this is problem

Comment: Ahh Okay , I understood you , I will edit thanks

Comment: Any help or suggestion please ? :/